# Get end position with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I would like to get the end token position while parsing with Parsec.

For instance, if I use the `identifier` combinator in the following way:

```
test = do
    start <- getPosition
    result <- identifier
    end <- getPosition
```

The `end` will not point to the end of the identifier. It will point to the next token (skipping spaces).

I could write my own `identifier` combinator to get the end position before skipping spaces, but I wonder if there is anything already doing this in Parsec.

Is there a way to get the end position of a combinator with Parsec?

Comment: isn't it just `start` plus the length of `result`?

Comment: Well, in this case, yes. But in more complex cases (multi-line string or function definitions) it will be harder to compute the end position.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `identifier` from `Text.Parsec.Token`, I don't think this will be easy.  `identifier` is defined using `lexeme`:

```
identifier =
    lexeme $ try $
    do{ name <- ident
      ; if (isReservedName name)
         then unexpected ("reserved word " ++ show name)
         else return name
      }
```

and `lexeme` consumes the whitespace:

```
lexeme p
    = do{ x <- p; whiteSpace; return x  }
```

which means by the time you get the result from `identifier`, the end position of the identifier is lost.

I don't think there is an elegant solution.  An ugly one is to copy the definition of `makeTokenParser` from `Text.Parsec.Token` and change its definition of `lexeme` so that it doesn't skip the whitespace.  Then you can have this:

```
myMakeTokenParser :: (Stream s m Char)
                  => GenLanguageDef s u m -> GenTokenParser s u m
myMakeTokenParser languageDef
    = TokenParser{ identifier = identifier
                 , reserved = reserved
    ...
  lexeme p = p
    ...
  }

lexer = myMakeTokenParser haskellDef
identifier' = identifier lexer
test = do
  start <- getPosition
  result <- identifier'
  end <- getPosition
  return (result, (start, end))

main = parseTest test "abc   def   "

> :main
("abc",((line 1, column 1),(line 1, column 4)))
```

Of course, now you need to be careful because the parsers won't skip whitespace any more.  An alternative would be to make `lexeme` record the position of the end of the inner parser (e.g. `identifier`) as part of the "user state", then skip the whitespace as usual.  You could then retrieve the end position from the user state.